# Taking powers of conjugates in group theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was trying to prove that $x^n=1$ (order of $x \in G$ is 1) implies that $(gxg^{-1})^n=1$ and after getting stuck and looking at a proof, I saw that person start by showing $(gxg^{-1})^n = gx^ng^{-1}$. If I accept that and follow through, I can understand the proof but I don't understand why $(gxg^{-1})^n = gx^ng^{-1}$ and not $(gxg^{-1})^n = g^nx^ng^{-n}$.

My problem is not understanding how powers work on conjugates. Why does it only affect the element that is being conjugated?

Comment: Why all the irrelevant tags? This is about groups, not about rings, fields, or Galois Theory.

Comment: Look at some actual examples: $(gxg^{-1})^3 = gxg^{-1}gxg^{-1}gxg^{-1} = gx^3g^{-1}$ since the two inner terms $g^{-1}g$ simplify to the identity. More generally, $gxg^{-1}gyg^{-1}gzg^{-1} = g(xyz)g^{-1}$, so the product of conjugates is the conjugate of the product.  For any number of terms this works.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that in general groups, powers don't distribute, i.e. you don't necessarily have $(xy)^n = x^n y^n$.  If that's why you thought you should get $(g x g^{-1})^n = g^n x^n g^{-n}$.  (In *abelian* groups, on the other hand, you do get the result $n(x+y) = nx + ny$ if you write in additive notation, or $(xy)^n = x^n y^n$ if you write in multiplicative notation; but then in abelian groups, conjugation is trivial anyway.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to MSE!

Notice the "inside" $g$s and $g^{-1}$s cancel. For example,

$$
(gxg^{-1})^2 = gxg^{-1}gxg^{-1} = gxxg^{-1} = gx^2g^{-1}.
$$

Can you show (by induction) that this continues to hold for $(gxg^{-1})^n$?

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: @Shaun, your edits are prolific, haha

Comment: Hahaha, thank you! I'd trade that for writing answers like yours any day of the week though :)

Comment: <3 ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Thank you! This is very clear.